# How do I write a mathematical equation for ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,1,0)[12] and How to substitute values of coefficients in that formula. Please help

Tags: arima

How do I write a mathematical equation for ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,1,0)[12] and How to substitute values of coefficients in that formula.
My model is

```
ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,1,0)[12]
## ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,1,0)[12] 
## 
## Coefficients:
##          ar1     sar1
##       0.6606  -0.5763
## s.e.  0.1143   0.1295
```

Comment: please let us know what the $(1,0,0)(1,1,0)[12]$ number denote?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered in various ways, providing you a good set of resources: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+formula+answers%3A1 .